# Настройка proxy_pass в конфиге nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, config

Не получается настроить конфиг nginx для перенаправления запросов.
Работает нормально только отдача статики для главной страницы и документации.
Все же прочие запросы, которые также начинаются с префикса `api/<VERSION>/<PATH>` мне нужно отдавать моему серверу (работающему на 3001 порту) вместе с query параметрами (если они есть).

Пока же nginx на полный запрос: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/text/to/text?source=hello`
просто отдает моему серверу `/`. Вместо полного пути.

Я так понял регулярки при проксировании вообще нельзя использовать? А как же задать множество вариантов путей, которые могут быть в API?

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        #server_name  localhost;
        #charset windows-1251;
        #charset koi8-r;
        root  www;
        
        location = / {
            root   www/assets;
            index  index.html;
            expires 10m;
        }
        
        location /api {
            alias   www/doc/;
            index  index.html;
            expires 10m;
        }
        
        
        location /api/v1.0/text/to/text {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте `proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;` (без последнего слеша)

Comment: Да, так заработало. Я правильно понимаю, что придется сделать свой locaton для каждого варианта api/<VERSION>/<PATH> ?

Comment: Нет, зачем? На стороне бэкэнда это уже.

Comment: По крайней мере, вот так:   location ~ /api/*/(text|file)/*        не работает.

Comment: В общем, просто сократил путь до /api/v1.0  и все. Главное, что весь путь уходит. Только версий API у меня тоже не одна. Значит на другую версию - свой location? Я просто очень мало с этим работал и не понимаю как нужно правильно такие вещи настраивать... Так что извиняйте за наив :-)